# How to turn off permanent highlighting of all braces (not just pairs) in vim

Tags: vim, editors

I have no idea how I modified vim such that all braces are highlighted, not just matching ones, but I want to turn it off now. How do I do that? The usual highlighting of matching braces works fine.

Comment: Obviously, you forgot to mention in what editor is this behavior.

Comment: @alex obviously he tagged it vim

Comment: @xenoterracide: ok, my bad.  Still putting it straight from the start wouldn't hurt anybody, and tags are very easy to overlook, IMHO.

Comment: What happens if you `:syn off`?

Comment: It turned up out of nowhere and it disappeared by itself,

Answer (score 2):

It could be a plugin called [pi_paren](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_paren.html).
You should be able to turn it off by executing `NoMatchParen` (and `DoMatchParen` to turn it back on).

If you want to turn it off permanently, add (to your `.vimrc`):

```
NoMatchParen
```

Comment: not this one either unfortunately.The quest continues.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a search for a brace? If you did then you can either search for gibberish, or you can do a `:set nohlsearch` to turn off highlighting.

Comment: That was my first thought. No, it's something else.

Comment: Or `:let @/ = ''`, which will clear the search pattern so you can leave `hls` on.  (Even if it apparently doesn't matter, for OP)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your ~/.viminfo file and start again.

Comment: bah humbug, just lost history but solved nothing